# How do I move files as large group with bluetooth from my phone to PC?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Razr I want to move all my pictures from my Razr to my PC.  I can do it one at a time by using bluetooth telling the computer to receive a file and then send it to the PC.  This takes a long time because I have to do it one at a time.

Is there any way I can do it as a large group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that a few phones allow you to queue more than one file and they simply send one at a time... I have no idea if Razr supports this.

If you have a large amount of files, you are probably best of buying a usb cable and transferring that way.

Alternatively, I hate the way phones come with bloated applications with useless features, but some of them come with the function of file transfer / phone browser, so it may be worth seeing if there is a phone suite for your one (use Vmware workstation or something similar to install if I was you).

Lastly, If there is no official program, there are a ton of paid applications that are meant to help you use your phone, it is worth seeing if there are any trials that allow you to do this. Again, you can install this sort of program in Vmware Workstation and pass through your USB bluetooth adapter to the virtual machine.